# I have 1 object, inside the object there is 1 array, how do I loop the array in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have one object, inside the object there is one array, how do I loop the array?

```
export class DetailMerchant extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nav1: null,
      nav2: null,
      detailMerchant:[]
    };
  }

  UNSAFE_componentWillMount(){
    const id = this.props.match.params.id_merchant
    this.setState({
      MERCHANT_ID:id,
    })
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await Api.post('/merchant-detail', this.state)
    .then((response) => {
      const responseJson = response
      if (responseJson.data.STATUS_CODE === '200') {
        this.setState({
          nav1: this.slider1,
          nav2: this.slider2,
          detailMerchant:responseJson.data.DATA
        });
      }
    })
  }

  render() {

    const detailMerchant = this.state.detailMerchant
    console.log(detailMerchant)

   const imgMerchant = detailMerchant.map(data => {
   return (<img src={data.merchant_id})
   })

    return (
      <Container>
       {imgMerchant}

      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

I tried imgMerchant looping, but TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

what am I doing is correct? but I'm trying to be fine, only when detailMerchant contains an object that has many properties in one of the properties there is an array type merchant_all_img

Comment: Means that `state.detailMerchant` isn't an array at the time the error gets thrown. You haven't shown how or when it gets defined

Comment: what kind of implementation can be shown ?, because I have tried it on console.log, the results are arrays,thanks

Comment: But where and when do you do the logging? my guess is you are using asynchronous request to get the data and calling `setState` after you receive it. If so it won't be there when initial `render()` gets called

Comment: A simple conditional render is probably what you need. Lots of resources around including the react docs on how to do a conditional render

Comment: can you give an example directly?

Comment: Try just doing `const detailMerchant = this.state.detailMerchant || [];`. You still haven't shown us how you define `state.detailMerchant` or where

Comment: Can you try logging what `detailMerchant` is and post it here??

Comment: it's true that when the first rendering state is empty, then after I setState in the componentDidMount state it already contains data, how do I handle it?

Comment: In the constructor do the following: `detailMerchant:[]`

Comment: @HMR I've tried it but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Check your responsJson.data.DATA